# Need help proving a statement about non-negative functions and integration

Tags: analysis

[image: a]![a]

I've proved question 2 and I'm on question 3,

using the hint, I'm having troubles deducing why $f(x) > \alpha /2$ - I think from there the answer is given (you get a contradiction with $d \leq c$)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Think about the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity.